# Adding base styles in layer

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

I am trying to add base styles to layer like in this [link](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/adding-custom-styles#adding-base-styles). It works fine in the [playground](https://play.tailwindcss.com/8MeKuXvXAd?file=css) but I am having trouble in the project. I am getting the default button settings from assumably the `base` layer.

[image: Browser Developer tools]

Specific problem or issue:

There is no trouble trying to override the `h3` tag, but for the `button` tag, I am unable to override the CSS and is instead with the default `background-color: transparent;` value, which points to the line where the tailwind `base` is initialized or loaded.

Shortest code to reproduce:

CSS

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
@layer base {
  h3 {
    @apply text-2xl bg-slate-200;
  }

  button {
    @apply bg-fuchsia-700
  }
}
```

HTML

```
<h3>This is h3</h3>
<button>This is button</button>
```

I am using tailwindcss in `NextJs` ^13.5.3 app using page router. Issue found in tailwindcss `v3.3.3` and `v3.4.1` as well

Comment: [Please don't post images of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors).

Comment: Actual code is updated as well. Image can help give additional information like the [adage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_picture_is_worth_a_thousand_words)

Comment: No, there's nothing in that image that wouldn't be better communicated as code within the question instead of a screenshot. Posting images of code will result in downvotes and question closures.

Comment: All the CSS part I doubt if it can be clearly communicated with code from the browser developer tools. The HTML can be, but again can lead to non legible code. Having said that, the code is already updated a long time ago.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The matching selector of the rule in Tailwind's preflight styles in your screenshot is `[type="button"]` which has a specificity of 0, 1, 0, whereas your `button` selector only has a specificity of 0, 0, 1. Consider matching Tailwind's selector to ensure you override it in your own styles:

```css
…
@layer base {
  …
  button, [type="button"], [type="reset"], [type="submit"] {
    @apply bg-fuchsia-700;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this answer helped. I am however looking to make image from svg url like below.
```
data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 24 24'%3E%3Cpath d='M12.2 13l3.4 6.6c.6 1.1 2.5-.4 2-1.2l-4-6.2z'/%3E%3Ccircle cx='10.8' cy='8.9' r='3.9' fill='none' stroke='%23000' stroke-width='1.5'/%3E%3C/svg%3E
```
Tailwind documentation talks about url image loading [here](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/background-image#arbitrary-values') but not much about the settings which need to be passed.